# Is it safe to remove plug fuses without cutting power first?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

My house has an old fuse box instead of a breaker box.

If I need to cut power to a room can I just remove that specific fuse from the box temporarily or should I cut all power to that box?

It'd be great to not have to shut off power to the majority of my house to just replace an outlet or a switch in one room but I don't want to be doing something unnecessarily risky either.

Thank you!

Comment: You'll be fine just removing the fuse. Test the outlets with a meter or plug in a light to make sure the outlet is de-energized.  Turn off any appliances and equipment with their "off" buttons before removing the fuse.

Answer (score 2):

The safest method is to turn any loads off that are on that circuit then remove the fuse.
By removing the loads you reduce the arc and possible arc flash that is increased with a load.

Answer (score 0):

You should be cutting power to the whole house *anyway*.

We see many cases on here where people get bit because the panel had unexpected surprises for them, such as *multi-wire branch circuits*.

That is particularly the case where very old work is involved.